# Split multiple lines into an array

Tags: bash

If i have a string called s that is stored as:

```
1 2  
5 6  
9 8
```

How do I split it into an array called myarray, such that

```
myarray[0] = 1 2  
myarray[1] = 5 6
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the internal field separator to a newline:

```
s='1 2
5 6
9 8'
IFS=$'\n' myarray=( $s )
echo ${myarray[1]}
```

Comment: I did that and it worked perfectly for myarray[0], but when I tried to echo myarray[1], it outputted nothing.

Comment: @james: What exactly is in $s?

Comment: The stored string, i.e. 1 2 \n5 6 \n9 8

Comment: @james: Did you try the edited code? I'm getting `5 6`.

Comment: @james: I only added the definition of $s.

Answer (score -3):

Well

```
String s = "1 2 \n5 6 \n9 8 \n5 4 \n1 2 \n";
String[] myarray = s.split("\n");
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Have you noticed the `bash` tag?

Comment: @Maarten - "clearly I have!"... are you sure?  I can't tell if you're being a troll, or if you're legitimate.  To put it another way that you'll understand, the solution you provided is not in `bash`.  That looks like Java/JavaScript.